# Databricks writes to Kafka autorization problem

Tags: apache-spark, authentication, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Databricks to send some data to Kafka:

```
(df.write
  .format('kafka')
  .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'glider.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094')
  .option('kafka.security.protocol', 'SASL_SSL')
  .option('kafka.sasl.mechanism', 'SCRAM-SHA-512')
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='my_username' password='my_password';")
  .option('topic', '<my_topic>')
  .save())
```

but it fails with message:

```
An error occurred while calling o2296.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 31.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 31.0 (TID 251) (ip-10-172-216-86.us-west-2.compute.internal executor driver): kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Cannot execute transactional method because we are in an error state
...
Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed.]
```

Credentials and security protocols are 100% correct as it works fine if I send data using Python's "confluent_kafka" library.

Any idea what's wrong with here? Maybe some option(s) must be adjusted?

I tried to specify different module

```
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='my_username' password='my_password';")
```

but the result was the same.